# How can I copy the full URL of my app onto the clipboard

Tags: google-earth-engine, url

I developed a parameterized App for computing a number of spectral (and spatial) indices from user-defined coposites:

https://jsilvan.users.earthengine.app/view/indices-espectrales-globales

Once configured, the maps can be shared by copying the link from the link bar in the browser.
What I would like is the user to be able to copy the link to the clipboard by clicking a button within the app.

So I wonder if there is a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no clipboard interactions available in the API.